# How to send mails using SMTP server in Linux without error

Tags: smtp, mail-command

I'm trying to send mail via SMTP server. And set `/etc/mail.rc` file with:

```
set bsdcompat
set smtp=smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465
set smtp-auth=login
set smtp-auth-user=user@gmail.com
set smtp-auth-password=password
set ssl-verify=ignore
set nss-config-dir=/etc/pki/nssdb/
```

Now I'm able to send mail, but I'm getting an error like:

```
Error in certificate: Peer's certificate issuer is not recognized.
```

> following entries are present in my nssdb:

**certutil -L -d /etc/pki/nssdb**

```
Certificate Nickname Trust Attributes 
                     SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI
```

Can anyone please suggest me a solution for this? I have googled, but didn't get a correct solution.

Comment: I assume that isn't a real user name and password you posted, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your `certutil -L -d /etc/pki/nssdb` output, your nssdb is empty!

With `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 </dev/null` you can dump the public part of the certificate of the mail server, and of any issuer certificates it may be offering. The output will be quite long, but first you should pay attention to these lines:

```
Server certificate
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=smtp.gmail.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
```

and

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=smtp.gmail.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
[...]
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
   i:/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
```

So, the server (`subject=` line if the Server certificate part and the certificate `0` in the `Certificate chain` part) is `smtp.gmail.com`, and its certificate was issued by "Google Internet Authority G3". That, in turn, has got its certificate from `GlobalSign Root CA - R2`.

A quick Google search with keywords "globalsign root ca R2" indicates that is a rather old certificate which will expire in 2021. If you trust it, you can download it [here](https://secure.globalsign.net/cacert/Root-R2.crt)... but exporting a copy of "Google Internet Authority G3" certificate from your web browser's built-in standard certificate store might be a better idea.

Whichever certificate you choose, once you have it in a file, you can import it into your nssdb with `certutil -A -d /etc/pki/nssdb -i <certificate file>`. (If the certificate is exported in PEM format, you may need to add the `-a` option.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your local system is missing certificates. Over on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) is an answer to this same question.

[smtp.gmail.com from bash gives "Error in certificate: Peer's certificate issuer is not recognized."](https://serverfault.com/questions/498588/smtp-gmail-com-from-bash-gives-error-in-certificate-peers-certificate-issuer)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. If the other site goes away your answer becomes worthless. Instead, please extract the relevant parts and add them to your answer here. (It's good still to reference the original source, to give credit.)

Comment: that post is not helping me..

Comment: certutil -L -d /etc/pki/nssdb

**Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI**

above certificates are present in my nssdb .

Comment: The error message suggests a problem with the certificates but your question doesn't contain enough information to diagnose the exact problem. Please edit your question to include full details.

Comment: edited @tripleee

Comment: The output looks like there are no certificates. How can you conclude that "above certificates are present in my nssdb"?